# Concatenating package and class names (java reflection)

Tags: java, reflection, package

I have a `Package` instance and a `Class` name as a string.

Is there any elegant way to concatenate them (so I can run `Class.forName()` on the result)?

I could of course just extract the string from the package and add a period between it and the class name, but there must be a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: Why do you think that concatenating the two is not an elegant way?
String fqcn = packageName + "." + className;
or
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(packageName);
sb.append(".");
sb.append(className);

Comment: As @anacron suggested, concatenating is a good way, but if you want something else, use a `StringBuilder` to append.

Comment: I was thinking that there must be a way to get the class from the package and then use it's name, or some function that concatenates packages to classes similarly to what there is with directories and files (paths).

Answer (score 2):

There's no special facility to joining simple class names with their package names, you'd have to do this yourself:

```
Package package = Package.getPackage("java.lang");
String simpleClassName = "String";
Class clazz = Class.forName (package.getName() + "." + simpleClassName);
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I'm doing, just thought that there should be something similar to directory and file concatenation.